# Trying to apply tags to multiple items when there is a tag limit and at least one of the items may be at that limit

Tags: multi-selection, tagging

I have a situation where we allow our users to select multiple items and apply tags to them as a group. But there is an 8 tag limit. The problem comes when I pick (e.g.) 3 items. Item A has 8 tags already, items B and C have 1 tag. I can't apply any more tags to item A. It would be easy to say "item A has too many" but there's not an easy and/or clear way to say this if the number of selections gets larger. Like if I were to select 30 items and 25 of them are at the limit, etc.

The simple answers are to remove the tag limit or not allow multi-select tagging or not allow the tagging action if they pick one with 8 already. But I'm curious if anyone has a more creative answer or idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem exists because you have conflicting requirements. But you forgot to mention why those requirements exist. Why is there a tag limit? Why is tagging multiple items needed? It’s important to give context to the question to get valuable answers.